# badge_label_helper.rb is failing to load in resque jobs

Tags: rubygems, resque, ruby-on-rails-5.1, resque-scheduler

We are trying to upgrade rails from 4.2 to 5.1.4 along with resque gem. 
But we got below results on the same.

**File : /lib/tasks/resque.rake
    require 'resque/tasks'
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    require 'resque/scheduler/server'
    require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
    task "resque:setup" => :environment do
        ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
        ENV['COUNT'] = '5'
        require 'resque'
        require 'resque-scheduler'
    end**

```
*Error: rake aborted!
LoadError: No such file to load -- badge_label_helper.rb*
```

*_Trace : QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work --trace
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
rake aborted!
LoadError: No such file to load -- badge_label_helper.rb
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in`block in load_file'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in`load_file'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in`block in load_interlock'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in`exclusive'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in`load_interlock'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:335:in`depend_on'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require_dependency'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in`block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in`block in eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in`eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/tasks.rb:45:in`each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/tasks.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in`block in execute'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in`execute'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in`mon_synchronize'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:217:in`block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in`invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in`mon_synchronize'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in`invoke'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:153:in `invoke_task'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in`block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in`block in top_level'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:118:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in`top_level'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `block in run'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:179:in`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rake:23:in`'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload_
Command :QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
"
_rake aborted!
LoadError: No such file to load -- badge_label_helper.rb
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in`block in load_file'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in`load_file'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in`block in load_interlock'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in`exclusive'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in`load_interlock'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:335:in`depend_on'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require_dependency'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in`block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in`block in eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in`eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/tasks.rb:45:in`each'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/tasks.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/dinilv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload
(See full trace by running task with --trace)_
"*

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same strange issue. It was working before, but when I reorganised my Gemfile it broke. After a lot of trying I found the solution:
The resque-web may not be put into a group.
Before:

```
group :production do
  gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web' # This will break
  gem 'resque-pool'
end
```

After:

```
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web' # Now it works
group :production do
  gem 'resque-pool'
end
```

Hope i could help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had to move resque-web above the resque gem and also add require: 'resque_web'